# Xcode 12.2 beta 3 / Big Sur Beta 10 throw SIGCONT for SwiftUI app

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I've just 'upgraded' to the latest Big Sur  – 11.0 Beta (20A5395g) – and Xcode betas – 12.2 beta 3 (12B5035g). When I try to run any SwiftUI based Mac App the program stops with a `Thread 1: signal SIGCONT` message. Sometimes I am able to continue (Ctrl Command Y), but others the program stops with the message `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 19`.

The Stack trace suggests the problem is in the ImageLoader.

I've tried reinstalling Xcode and clearing out it's cache's. The problem even manifests with a brand new project - i.e. it isn't related to my code,

Any ideas how I might trouble shoot this?

Comment: Submit feedback to Apple, betas are test drops - especially for that purpose.

Comment: Yup - added feedback and see its been raised on the apple dev forums...

Comment: This now is fixed in Big Sur - 11.0.1 Beta

Answer (score 17):

You can workaround the issue using a symbolic breakpoint.

Add a symbolic breakpoint with the following settings:

**Symbol**: _main
**Module**: dyld
**Action**: *Debugger Command* with the command `process handle -n false -s false SIGCONT`
**Options**: *Check Automatically continue after evaluating actions*

[image: Example symbolic breakpoint]

Answer (score 7):

Workaround by choosing "Debug Process as Root" in Schema "Run" -> "Info"

[Apple Forum discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663823?page=1#640854022)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Big Sur beta10 and xcode12 beta1.
Removing "**debug executable**" tick in run-debug scheme page fixed it for me.
You can get there by **Product->Scheme->edit scheme...**

Here is a screenshot:

[image]